# Getting variable data outside subscribe method function

Tags: angular

I want to create a function that return an object from service that uses external API. I am not able to make it work.

```
GetMatchinfo (matchid : number  ) : Match {

    let aq :Match;

    this.matchService.GetMatch(matchid).subscribe(
        (Matchinfodata: Match)=>{     
            aq=Matchinfodata;
         }
    ); 

    return aq;

}
```

Comment: You have to put the return inside subscription.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the function from template, just move the position of return call to subscription block. Or if you are using the `GetMatchInfo()` inside some other function, it's better to use observable and subject.

```
GetMatchInfo (matchid : number  ) : Observable<Match> {

    let aq = new Subject<Match>();

    this.matchService.GetMatch(matchid).subscribe(
        (Matchinfodata: Match)=>{     
            aq.next(Matchinfodata);
         }
    ); 

    return aq.asObservable();

}
```

And subscribe to `GetMatchInfo()` function somewhere you require.

```
this.GetMatchInfo(id).subscribe(
    (result) => {
        console.log(result)
    }
);
```